# Spark and sequence files

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I'm using sequence file to aggregate a number of binary records in single HDFS file. I'd like to access each of these aggregated files in Spark using stream API (e.g. as InputStream or DataInputStream) similar to how SparkContext.binaryFiles() works for regular files.

Is there a similar API that would return an InputStream for each binary chunks stored in the sequence file?

Another question is if Spark will load local blocks from HDSF node to memory, or rather one Spark process will read whole sequence file on a single node to create distributed RDD?